# Git: Remove single file from branch, whilst keeping it in the project

Tags: git

At some point I must have edited a file unrelated to the branch (issue) I was working on. I accidentally pushed it to Github and saw it when I created a Pull Request.

I want to remove the file from my branch, but not from the project - ie: I just can't delete the file and push that as a commit.

I've tried:

`git reset HEAD^ path/file.ext`

but had no luck (nothing happened - no errors and the file didnt revert).

Would anyone know the right way of going about this?

Comment: Yes, you can just delete the file from that branch. It won't affect the rest of the project unless you merge the branch.

Comment: @Schwern but I do want to merge the branch eventually. And wont it show as a deleted file in my commits?

Comment: Yes, but it won't be in the final merge. So unless it's sensitive, doesn't much matter.

Comment: @Schwern this is where my knowledge of git weakens: By signaling that a file has been deleted wont that then be marked as a deleted file in future merges? Isn't it a form of 'modifying' the file?

Comment: *Very generally*, how the files in a branch got changed doesn't matter. All that matters to the merge is what everything looks like at the tip of the branch. This is why people say Git "tracks content" rather than "tracks changes" or "tracks deltas". Each commit in Git is, conceptually, the complete state of the files. The history of how things changed is just that: history. So if you add a file in a branch, and then delete it later in the same branch, as far as the merge is concerned it never existed.

Comment: MeltingDog and @Schwern: this is where it's critical to be careful about phrasing. Your original question makes it sound like *maybe* you added this as a *new* file on the branch, or *maybe* you just changed it and want to "un-change" it. As Schwern says, what matters to Git is the overall change from base to tip. If the file was in the base, and is not in the tip, *then* Git sees it as "deleted". Unfortunately, this requires getting into figuring out "what is the base". That's not quite rocket surgery or brain science, but it's also not totally trivial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From what it sounds like, you basically want to remove all the changes for the file in your merge request.  The first thing to do is checkout a clean copy of the file and add it to your branch.

```
git checkout master -- <the file>
```

Now commit these changes and push the new commit to your remote.  The pull request should be updated to no longer have the changes to this file.

If you are the only person that has used the branch, you can rebase your commits so that this latest commit is no longer in your history (but it really isn't a big deal).  For that you would `git rebase -i master`, choosing to "squash" the commits.  In order to update the commits in the pull request, you will need to do `git push -f <your branch>`.  So that the new commits overwrite, the old ones.  This step is completely optional.

Comment: Yes! Thanks! Sorry, I probably should have phrased my question like that

Comment: git checkout Rl_branch -- file.java

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a sensitive file, you can just delete it and push the new commit.

```
git rm that_file
git commit
git push
```

The file will still in the history, but it won't appear in the final merge.

If it's a sensitive file, like it has passwords or personal information in it. Or if you just want to provide a cleaner history, you can remove it from history with `git rebase -i master` (or whatever branch you branched from). This will give you the opportunity to rewrite the commit that accidentally included that file. Rewrite the commit, and `git push --force` to send the new version of your branch history up.

Rather than going into detail, I'll refer you to the [Rewriting History chapter of Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

Answer (score 1):

How many commits are there on this single file? Simplest way is to rebase from master and edit those commits, like this:

```
git rebase -i master
# find the relevant commits and use `edit` instead of `pick`
git reset --soft HEAD~1 -- file # makes the changed file staged to be commit (but we don't want that)
git checkout -- file # revert the changes staged again in the previous command
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
git push --force origin <your-branch-name>
```

You should now have a clean commit history without any changes in the specific file.